# Are there any nice restaurants or cafes offering Wi-Fi and power outlets in Lyon?

Tags: france, restaurants, wifi, cafes, lyon

I am a telecommuter looking for a nice place to work out of in Lyon this week. Do you have any recommendations?

What I am looking for is free Wi-Fi, power outlets close to seating and preferably a low-key atmosphere. Good coffee is a bonus.

My hotel is just east of the Rhone near Lafayette, but anywhere near the city centre is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this [article](http://cyrusfarivar.com/blog/2009/04/30/lyon-wifi-cafes/#comments) giving a few options. Especially the second one seems to fit your criteria:

> Lipstick
>   19, Rue Désirée
>   M: Hôtel de Ville
>
> This café is a close second to the Voxx. There’s a nice little vibe and they have great booths if you’re staying for lunch. If not, they’re happy to let you sit at the bar and check your email or do whatever else. Most of the booth tables have power plugs.